# How can I run a latexmk cleanup for subdirectory?

Tags: latexmk

I'm writing a command line tool that does some work with `latexmk`. I specify a specific directory with `output-directory`.

However when I run `latexmk -c subdirectory` nothing happens.

Can I do that with `latexmk` or do I have to change the working directory?

Answer (score 2):

No, the current version doesn't do what you ask.  You can just do something like "pushd subdirectory; latexmk -c; popd", which you could automate with a script or an alias.

Comment: This gives me `Latexmk: No file name specified, and I couldn't find any.` Ideas?

Comment: I have the same question. Has anything changed? Ideally I'd like to be able to do `latemk -C subdir`. Or even `latexmk -C subdir/file.tex` would work. But neither work as of `4.70b`. Unlike the poster, `pushd` and `popd` do work for me.